# Error handling using JQuery Terminal Plugin and Django with jsonrpc

Tags: jquery, django, json-rpc, jquery-terminal

Just having some fun, and trying to learn both JQuery and Django at the same time. I thought it would be nifty to write a browser based terminal application.

Here's the background:

- My application uses the jsonrpc django-json-rpc here:
  https://github.com/samuraisam/django-json-rpc And the Jquery terminal
  plugin here: http://terminal.jcubic.pl/

My console page looks like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static "goat/jquery.terminal-0.7.10.min.js" %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "goat/jquery.terminal.css" %}">
  </head>
<body>
    <div id="term"></div>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#term').terminal("http://goatgruff.com/json/", {
        greetings: "Menu: (R)egister (L)ogin"});
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My json views.py uses the same examples as the json-rpc does...

```
from jsonrpc import jsonrpc_method

    @jsonrpc_method('sayHello')
    def whats_the_time(request, name='Lester'):
      return "Hello %s" % name

    @jsonrpc_method('gimmeThat', authenticated=True)
    def something_special(request, secret_data):
      return {'sauce': ['authenticated', 'sauce']}
```

Cool. So the question:

When I type in my terminal "sayHello Matt" the Ajax call works and responds with "Hello Matt." Just ducky. But if I type in a method that isn't in views.py I get an ugly AJAX error.

I would like to handle this error nicely, and tell the user that there's not method. Since I have to name methods in the view, I can't have an error handler there. I wonder if I should put a try / catch in the urls.py or if my JQuery should handle the error by parsing whatever comes back - I am not sure what that object would look like and how I would get at the result.

A few pointers in the right direction would help me learn.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: What kind of JSON exactly do you get from python where there is no method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out on my own. First I started monkeying around in the exceptions.py file in jsonrpc. But rather than override the error messages coming from jsonrpc, it seemed better to just make a simple error response from JQuery Terminal. So I just commented the more informative response and return a generic 'invalid command' to save the user from seeing verbosity they wouldn't understand.

```
      function make_basic_json_rpc_interpreter(url) {
        var service = function(method, params) {
            self.pause();
            $.jrpc(url, method, params, function(json) {
                if (!json.error) {
                    display_object(json.result);
                } else {
                    self.error('&#91;RPC&#93; ' + json.error.message);
                }
                self.resume();
            }, function(xhr, status, error) {
                if (status !== 'abort') {
                    //self.error('&#91;AJAX&#93; ' + status +
                    //               ' - Server reponse is: \n' +
                    //               xhr.responseText);
                    self.error('Invalid Command');
                }
                self.resume();
            });
```

Comment: I've added callbacks: `onAjaxError`, `onRPCError` and also `processRPCResponse` where you can specify how you want to display the results from RPC.